# Creating a content editable word processor using Vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm interested in developing a word processor type application with a structure like this:

```
Document -> pages -> paragraphs
```

I essentially want to get to a point where I'm able to do something like this:

```
var page_4_content = document.pages[4].paragraphs;
```

This document would need to be `contenteditable`. I've already built a rudimentary version using `jQuery` but it is slow as hell in processing all the paragraphs on a 100 page document. I've been looking at alternatives and was wondering if Vue will give me better performance and an easier way to manage the document content instead of having to use selectors all the time?

Specifically, pages have a fixed height so if adjusting an element causes the page height to change, the whole document needs to be repaginated and this locks up the browser.

I'm wondering if Vue's use of a virtual DOM will alleviate that problem?

Many thanks!